# how to generate grid points from scratch for a simple rectangular structure?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, arraylist, plot, grid

I just started learning CFD, i was given an assignment to generated grid point for various closed structures like rectangle, triangle and circle and the condition is that i'm not suppose to use high end built in functions in python.

Here i tried to get the grid points for a rectangular structure.
It would be very kind of you, if you could suggest any way to improve the code for grid point generation.
I might need to generate 100 000 points.

Here is my attempt

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create x point on horizonatal line
xinitial=0;xfinal=5;xnum=5
xi=np.linspace(xinitial,xfinal,num=xnum)
# print("\n xi= \n",xi,"\n"*2)

# create y point on vertiacl line
yinitial=0;yfinal=5;ynum=5
yi=np.linspace(yinitial,yfinal,num=ynum)
# print("\n yi= \n",yi,"\n"*2)

xygrid =np.array([[xa ,ya] for xa in xi for ya in yi])
# print("\n xygrid coordinates= \n",xygrid,"\n"*2)

xgrid, ygrid = xygrid.T
# print("\n xgrid coordinates= \n",xgrid,"\n"*2)
# print("\n ygrid coordinates= \n",ygrid,"\n"*2)

xmin=xinitial-2;xmax=xfinal+2
ymin=yinitial-2;ymax=yfinal+2

axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
plt.scatter(xgrid,ygrid)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just implement a `point in shape` test for each and parallelize the loops. That is how software rasterizers tend to work nowadays. The likes of scanline rasterization are obsolete IMHO with our multi-core computers and more so with random samples.

Comment: @ Dragon Energy , thank for the response. I should have mentioned that i'm new to python. I will work on it thanks again